# How do we create secondary indexes in Accumulo?

Tags: accumulo

I was reading the Accumulo documentation. I came across secondary indexes. Are these separate tables we need to create or these are internally created?

Answer (score 1):

Secondary indexes are not automatically created in Accumulo.

They are purely a concept which you, as an Accumulo user, are free to implement, depending on your application requirements.

Comment: Suggested edit to this answer: explain that the concept is typically implemented by the user as separate tables with a different schema (in other words, a table sorted in a different way from the user's other table).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of common options here (neither is ideal):

1. create a 2nd copy of the entire table, but indexed on the secondary column(s)
2. create a 2nd table that is simply a key/value lookup where the key is the
   value of the secondary column(s) and the value is the rowid of the
   corresponding row in the primary table

I expect the 2nd option to be more palatable soon given that, to quote the [Accumulo/Hive Integration documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AccumuloIntegration#AccumuloIntegration-Indexing):

> Starting with Hive 3, indexing has been added to Accumulo-backed Hive
>   tables. Indexing works by using another Accumulo table to store the
>   field value mapping to rowId of the data table. The index table is
>   automatically populated on record insertion via Hive.